Azure thinks of Performance testing with Jmeter as DDos attack
I have my APIs deployed on App services.
I have set up a basic Jmeter tests with 1000 concurrent users.
Now when I run that test, Azure thinks of it as DDoS attack, and temporarily stops the service.
I can think of rotating the IP addresses. But that too doesnt seem to be solution, considering the sophistication of Azure's checks.
How can I do the Load testing in such a case?


temporarily stops the service

what a great way of protecting a service from DDoS attack: simply turn it off.
We cannot provide a comprehensive answer without knowing how DDoS protection is organized so I can only give generic recommendations like:

Make sure that JMeter is configured to behave like a real browser
Correlate and parameterize your test so each virtual user would represent a real user
Under "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler there is possibility to specify source IP address if DDoS protection checks for concurrent requests from a single IP

And finally it's possible to run JMeter in distributed mode if you figure out the highest number of users which are accepted from a single load generator

